# Codeigniter login redirect looping error

Tags: codeigniter, loops, redirect

After i had changed my codeigniter files to another hosting it come out with this error. 
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects

It might cause by the infinity looping redirect in my code but i cant figure it out whats the error in my code

my route default controller is inside.php

here is the inside.php (controller) code

```
class Inside extends Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::Controller();
        $this->loginchk_model->is_logged_in();
    }

    function index(){
      $this->template->write('title', 'Update to date data');
      $this->template->write_view('header', 'header_content', true);
      $this->template->write_view('content', 'inside_view', true);
      $this->template->load();
    }
}
```

and here is the loginchk_model.php (model) code

```
class Loginchk_model extends Model{

    function is_logged_in(){
        //check session exist or not
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') && $this->session->userdata('username')){
        redirect('inside');
        die;
        }else{

        redirect('login');
        //echo anchor('login','Back to login page');
        die();
        }
}
}
```

and here is the login.php (controller) code

```
class Login extends Controller{

function __construct(){
parent::Controller();
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->model('his_action_model');
}

function index(){
         $data['title'] = 'Login in';

         $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
}
```

here is my htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foldername/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Stuck for few hours in this problem.. i am also wondering why changed hosting cause such problem.

thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

That issue could be because of your .htaccess I believe I had that issue before when going from local server to my host.  There was extra lines at the bottom of the .htaccess that were causing an issue on that particular server so I commented them out.  But I could be wrong.

Is this happening for just you or have you tried viewing the error from a different PC?

Comment: I had add my .htaccess code in. is there any error in my code? all these code run smoothly in one hosting, and another cant...

Comment: okie.. i found what is the problem and i dono why will cause such error... the hosting had close the Register Globals in php.ini and inside my  $config['uri_protocol'] i am using ORIG_PATH_INFO. after i had change it into auto... everything goes well..